# node_modules: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

Tags: node-modules

When I check out the preview of my project on GitHub, I get the error at all the files that are stored in node_modules folder.

[image]

The code:

```
<script src="./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

I've added .gitignore to the repository with node_modules in it, but nothing has changed.

It works perfectly on localhost, though. I use PhpStorm.

Comment: `node_modules` are being ignored (and they should). So jquery won't exist. Try running `npm i` at the root of your project (where `package.json` is located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

This line asks ther server that is serving the HTML file to serve `./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js`. Eventhough you didn't provide any server code, I'm going to take a wild guess and say that your server is not configured do to so (whether it's because node_modules are ignored by github or not), thus the 404.

Moreover, that is not the way that Node modules are normally used. You should instead use one of these statements in your JS file to use jQuery:

```
import $ from "jquery";
const $ = require('jquery');
```